# How to render an Object in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, amazon-cognito

I'm trying to render user data returned from AWS Cognito but I'm unable to save the obejcts state. This is the object that is returned from Cognito:

```
{
    "custom:type": "Donor",
    "sub": "48b8b2dd-7a7c-4cbf-b14e-cf70e55a9cd8",
    "address": "address1",
    "email_verified": false,
    "custom:abn": "12345678",
    "phone_number_verified": false,
    "given_name": "John",
    "custom:business_name": "Name of Business",
    "phone_number": "+1123456",
    "family_name": "Smith",
    "email": "test@gmail.com"
}
```

I am trying to store this object using the useState hook in react as shown in the code below. However, nothing seems to be stored in my attributes object. When I run console.log(attributes) in the last line it shows up as an empty object.

```
    const [attributes, setAttributes] = useState({});

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchAttributes();
      }, []);

    const fetchAttributes = async() => {
        try{
            const userData = await Auth.currentAuthenticatedUser();
            const attributesList = userData.attributes;
            console.log(attributesList);
            setAttributes(attributesList);
        } catch (error) {
            console.log('error in fetching user data', error);
        }

    };

    console.log(attributes);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the first render, the object is empty since the retrieval of the attributes takes some times.
If the attributes variable is used in the return, you should have a second render after the use of setAttributes with the filled object in the console